# Why are my camera roll photos not synching in the original resolution?

Tags: 8.0, onedrive

I have a Nokia Lumia 822 that started off working really well and then started freezing up once or more a day. Verizon shipped me a new phone but now my photos that are synced via OneDrive are no longer uploading to OneDrive in their original size.

Old 822 - 3264 x 2448
New 822 - 1279 x 959

I have OneDrive setup to use the original resolution as shown in this screenshot.

[image]

I've tried changing this setting and then changing it back, but they are still the small resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings you need are not in OneDrive. Go to*Phone Settings --> Backup --> Photos --> Best Quality*.

There is also the same option for videos.